# Jetpack compose scrollable table

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I need to have a component that scrolls vertically and horizontally.

Here is what I did so far:

```
@Composable
fun Screen() {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val scrollOffset = remember {
        mutableStateOf(value = 0F)
    }
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(space = 16.dp)
    ) {
        items(10) {
            SimpleRow(
                onScrollOffsetChange = {
                    scrollOffset.value = it
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun SimpleRow(
    onScrollOffsetChange: (Float) -> Unit,
) {
    val lazyRowState = rememberLazyListState()
    LazyRow(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        state = lazyRowState
    ) {
        item {
            Text(
                text = "firstText"
            )
        }
        for (i in 1..30) {
            item {
                Text(text = "qwerty")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When anyone of these `SimpleRow` is scrolled I want to scroll all of the `SimpleRow`s together.

And I do not know how many `SimpleRow`s I have because they came from our server.

Is there any kind of composable or trick that can do it for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple rows inside a column that scrolls horizontally and vertically, like this:

```
@Composable
fun MainContent() {
    val scrollStateHorizontal = rememberScrollState()
    val scrollStateVertical = rememberScrollState()

  Column(
      modifier = Modifier
          .fillMaxSize()
          .verticalScroll(state = scrollStateVertical)
          .horizontalScroll(state = scrollStateHorizontal)
  ) {
      
      repeat(40){ c ->
          Row {
              repeat(40){ r ->
                  Item("col: $c | row: $r")
              }
          }
      }
      
  }
}

@Composable
fun Item(text: String) {
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(5.dp)
            .background(Color.Gray),
        text = text,
        color = Color.White
    )
}
```

[image: sample image]

Comment: in this sample rows scroll independently!
I want to scrol them all at the same time

Comment: in my code rows are not scrollable, only thing that can scroll is the column and it can scroll vertically and horizontally and it contains all the rows so all of them will scroll together